# Каким образом здесь генерируется случайное число?

Tags: javascript

Прохожу курс в котором есть игра, нужно сгенерировать 4 случайных числа, не понимаю эти строки кода. Каким образом генерируется случайное число?

```
function generateNumber(){
  var min = 1;
  var max = 9;

  // заполняем массив цифр в числе
  for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    var part = Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min)+min); //5
    
    // первое число всегда уникально
    if(i == 0){
      number[0] = part;
    }
    else{ 
      // пока не сгенерируется уникальное число, генерируем новые случайные числа
      while(number.indexOf(part) != -1){//элемент найден
        part = Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
      }
        
      number[i] = part;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Что именно непонятно? `Math.random()` возвращает случайное число от 0 до 1, а дальше оно математически приводится к нужному диапазону значений (от 1 до 9)

Comment: while(number.indexOf(part) != -1){//элемент найден
    part = Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
   }

Comment: вот эту строчку можете объяснить? не понимаю как4им образом числа не повторяются и записываются в массив

Comment: `number.indexOf(part)` проверяет наличие объекта part в массиве number и возвращает его индекс, а если объекта нет — возвращает -1, что и проверяется в условии цикла

Comment: то есть если в массиве есть part то он его перезаписывает на другое число?

Comment: я не понимаю каким образом он понимает что такое число уже есть и перезаписывает его, мы же в массив записываем парт 4 раза, но как он определяет что такое число уже есть и генерирует новое

Comment: Не очень тебе повезло с курсом, если они предлагают такой код. `if/else` тут не к месту - первый элемент устанавливается до цикла, а `foo` начинается с `1`. Вместо `indexOf()` используется "правильный" метод `includes()`.

Comment: курс от GeekBrains, тут пока что все упрощено так как это можно сказать введение. К примеру тут даже переменные через var, а не let и const

Comment: Так и что тут непонятного, `while` будет "вертеться" до тех пор, пока не "сгенерится" число, которого нет в массиве. Но я бы это написал в одну строку без тела `while (number.includes(part = randomInt()));`